# How can I specify a void function in typed racket?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

What should be the type annotation of `foo`?

```
(define (foo)
  (println "hello"))
```

I tried these but none of them worked:

```
(: foo (-> () ()))
(: foo (-> Void Void))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `(-> Void Void)` is for a function that takes in a `void`, and returns a `void`. Your `foo` function, takes in no arguments, and returns a `void`. As such, the type you want for it is actually:

```
(: foo (-> Void))
(define (foo)
  (println "hello"))
```

As a side note:

If you wanted to modify `foo` to have the type `(-> Void Void)`, you could do this:

```
(define (foo _)
  (print "Don't do this though"))
```

As for:

```
(: foo (-> () ()))
```

That is syntactically invalid.

Comment: what's the difference between a function that takes in nothing and one that takes in "void"? I thought the two are just synonyms.

Comment: Unlike in languages like Java or C, void is an actual value in Racket. It is a singleton in that there is only one value, so returning it has little use. Since every function needs to return 'something', we use void when we don't want to return much of anything. Haskell's `Unit` is similar. This is why a function that takes in a `Void` actually take an argument, which only void can satisfy.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In this case Typed Racket can infer the type. Run this program:

```
#lang typed/racket
(define (foo)
  (println "hello"))
```

Then in the REPL you can write

```
> foo
- : (-> Void)
#<procedure:foo>
```

or

```
> (:print-type foo)
(-> Void)
```

to see that the type of foo is `(-> Void)`.
That is, it is a function of no argument that returns a value of type `Void` (that is, it returns `#<void>`.

Out final program becomes:

```
#lang typed/racket
(: foo : (-> Void))
(define (foo)
   (println "hello"))
```